# Authlogic Password_Reset TypeError (can't convert nil into String)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I am successfully using Authlogic and I am trying to add the ability for users to reset their password by [using this tutorial](http://www.binarylogic.com/2008/11/16/tutorial-reset-passwords-with-authlogic/). When I submit the request (to the PasswordResetsController#create action) to reset the password I am getting this error:

```
TypeError (can't convert nil into String):
  app/models/user.rb:19:in `deliver_password_reset_instructions!'
  app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

I have been through tutorial several times and also combed through the [sample app of it here](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example/tree/with-password-resets/app/). I can't seem to figure out what is going on. Anyone have any experience/direction on this implementation and error?

Here is the full terminal output:

```
Processing PasswordResetsController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-11 11:32:19) [POST]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Reset my password", "authenticity_token"=>"G2dtgfJJktJN7iX1FWPHvG5wjLKkIXEIZvJ72+zfSIk=", "email"=>"bgadoci@gmail.com"}
  User Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'bgadoci@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
  User Update (0.3ms)   UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = '2010-11-11 17:32:19', "perishable_token" = 'uu_LhCF77GCNbzYfHb2v' WHERE "id" = 1

TypeError (can't convert nil into String):
  app/models/user.rb:19:in `deliver_password_reset_instructions!'
  app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:12:in `create'

Rendered rescues/_trace (129.1ms)
Rendered rescues/_request_and_response (0.3ms)
Rendering rescues/layout (internal_server_error)
```

User.rb

```
  def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
      reset_perishable_token!
      Notifier.deliver_password_reset_instructions(self)
    end
```

Update:
I'm using rails 2.3.8 and ruby 1.8.7

Update:
Notifier.rb

```
 default_url_options[:host] = "foobar.com"  

 def password_reset_instructions(user)  
  subject       "Password Reset Instructions"  
  from          "foobar"  
  recipients    user.email  
  sent_on       Time.now  
  body          :edit_password_reset_url => edit_password_reset_url(user.perishable_token)  
 end
```

Update:
Here is the /views/notifier/password_rest_instruction.erb

```
A request to reset your password has been made. If you did not make this request, simply ignore this email. If you did make this request just click the link below:

<%= @edit_password_reset_url %>

If the above URL does not work try copying and pasting it into your browser. If you continue to have problem please feel free to contact us.
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the template? Are your referencing any instance variables with nil values?

Comment: I don't think so. I think it isn't accessing the perishable_token correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The output is telling you there's an error in line 19 of User#deliver_password_reset_instructions! Paste your code and I'll be able to help you more...

Comment: no idea... I would try commenting out some code. First 'reset_perishable_token!', second 'Notifier.deliver_password_reset_instructions(self)', third removing the urls from the email, and so on...

Comment: I feel like maybe it isn't loading the perishable_token correctly as the next line after reset_perishable_token is the one that is complaining that it can't converte nil to string. I tried commenting out everything and id didn't fix it.

Comment: they seem to work fine then... Try in the console 'User.first.reset_perishable_token!' and 'Notifier.deliver_password_reset_instructions(User.first)'.